# can not open sdk manager with terminal Mac OS

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I open my terminal to the `tools` directory of my `sdk` directory:

```
/Users/myusername/Library/Android/sdk/tools
```

and then I run below command to open the sdk manager:

```
./android
```

the result is:

```
-bash: ./android: Permission denied
```

I also tried:

```
 sudo ./android
```

but get below result:

```
sudo: ./android: command not found
```

does some one know what is the problem?

This is the result of `pwd`:

```
/Users/myuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools
```

Comment: The HomeBrew installation of the sdk tools is pretty reliable.

Comment: @cricket_007 may you please specify your comment more?

Comment: Can you post the output of `pwd` and `ls`?

Comment: `brew install android-sdk`... http://brew.sh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried "sudo chmod +x android" ? Chmod +x will make the binary executable chmod is a POSIX standard and you can find the man page online http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod

Comment: I recieved chmod: android: No such file or directory

Comment: /Users/myuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools

Comment: It was my bad, I had test chmod command at another directory. Thanks and I will accept the answer, but it will be better if you can add some information about what chmod command do .

Comment: chmod is a common unix command, used to change permissions of files and directories, you can find some useful help by typing in the terminal ```man chmod```. man works with a lot of terminal commands. 
If the man page is not available, you can also try with ```chmod --help``` most of the times it will show you some instructions on how to use it, and the purpose of the command.

Answer (score 1):

> ./android: Permission denied

You need to give permission, if you want to run the command as any user, then `755` for `-rwxr-xr-x`.

> sudo: ./android: command not found

You are in the wrong directory.

Just put the full path.

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/myusername/Library/Android/sdk/
sudo chmod 755 $ANDROID_HOME/tools/android
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the Android command-line tools, I often add a `ANDROID_HOME` system variable and edit the `PATH`. On a Mac, you can do this in `.bashrc` in your home directory:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/path/to/android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools:$PATH
```

Now this only makes it easier to do things at the command line. It doesn't solve the permission issues you are having. For that, you need to use `chmod` to ensure you have permission as the current user.